# How can I use snap.svg with external files?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I know I can use an inline `<svg>` element to load snap svg. However I would like to use an non-inlined file via an `<img>` element:

```html
<img alt="comparison" src={arcStatic('/images/comparison.svg')} />
```

```
var diagram = Snap('img'),
  group = diagram.select('#someGroup')
```

Where `someGroup` is an `svg` `g` element, fails. `group` is null.

Additionally:

```
console.log('diagram.constructor.name);
```

Shows this is an `Element` rather than a Snap instance.

**How can I use snap.svg with external files?**

Comment: you cannot access the DOM of img elements. Not not with anything.

Comment: @RobertLongson Fair enough - if you have a reference for that you're welcome to add it as an answer.

Comment: You can use an object tag, if that's any good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Paper.image` function: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.image and put the images into the page with snap, so that you can access them.